# how to give proper address of file and folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I have been trying all the day on this code I don't find why DIR shows an error in open CV module .
I need solution on this
'''

```
import os
import  cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
people=['emily','emma','jim parson']
haar_cas=cv.CascadeClassifier('haar_face.xml')
# 
DIR=r'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\New folder\faces'
features=[]
labels=[]
def train_face():
    for person in people:
        paths=os.path.join(path=DIR,people)
        label=people.index(person)
        

        for img in os.listdir(paths):

            img_path=os.path.join(path,img)
            img_array=cv.imread(img_path)
            gray=cv.cvtColor(src=img_array,code=cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            faces_rect=haar_cas.detectMultiScale(gray,scalefactor=1.1,minNeighbor=1)
            for(x,y,w,h) in faces_rect:

                faces_roi=gray[x:x+w , y:y+h]
                features.append(faces_roi)
                labels.append(label)

train_face()
print(f'length of the feature={len(features)}')
print(f'lenght of the labels={len(labels)}')
```

'''
the output displayy like this

```
'''
        File "g:\opencv\face_reconization.py", line 14
        paths=os.path.join(path=DIR,people)
                               ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
'''
```

Comment: Python has positional arguments and keyword arguments. Positional arguments need to be provided before keyword arguments. I recommend checking out the python documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think this `path=` is not necessary.
Change

```
   paths=os.path.join(path=DIR,people)
```

to

```
   paths=os.path.join(DIR,people)
```

Comment: it doesnot work it say  typeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'list'

Comment: instead od people, pass person like
paths=os.path.join(DIR,person)